# Update Rpi from Local Github Zip :: Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi2

I've downloaded a zip from [here](https://github.com/notro/rpi-firmware) on to my Raspberry Pi and want to run an update from it locally ("sudo REPO_URI=https://..." doesn't work because of apparently [common](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?&t=43060) issues, and connectivity).

**Question**: Is there a general way of installing github-based packages from a local zip copy instead of github.com?
**Follow-up**: Is there a general way wherein Raspberry Pi Updates can be downloaded as zip files from the site and pointed to locally, when running "sudo rpi-update"

**A bit about the zip file**: These are display drivers for the [Wave Share SpotPear](http://www.wvshare.com/product/3.2inch-RPi-LCD-B.htm) display which look like they're a part of a standard Raspberry Pi update.

**Things I have tried**: Following instructions [here](http://quick2wire.com/articles/a-gentle-guide-to-git-and-github/) I looked up the README, however it just asks to use the "sudo REPO_URI=https://.." command. I also tried simply replacing the value after REPO_URI with my local path, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need to download the contents (use GitHub's 'download zip' button) and then you can unzip the file and follow whatever instructions are necessary to make it happen.

Comment: Doesn't work - I wrote that I've already checked out the README and there's nothing of help in there. It's basically a copy of what's written on the git page - and asks to download off the page straight. Nothing about usage from the zip file